# I am not able to import module from S3 in glue job

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud

I have a Python file in my S3 bucket `s3://pymod_import_testing/hello_world.py` and I have a glue-job with the following `special-parameters` configured

```
--extra-py-files s3://pymod_import_testing/hello_world.py
--additional-python-modules s3://pymod_import_testing/hello_world.py
```

And when I do `import hello_world` in glue-job script I get `ModuleNotFound` error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

zip hello_world.py
add in glue job as --extra-py-files as a key and value
script_location: s3://<bucket_name>/etl_jobs/hello_world.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).